# Wordpress: How to change post_author to multiple wp_post IDs via SQL?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am trying to change the author_name of multiple posts in Wordpress. I'd prefer to use an SQL query instead of a Wordpress plugin. Is there a way to select multiple IDs in SQL and update? I'd like to get a list of all the post IDs I'd like to change and bulk edit the author name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a plugin, if you'd like, from the backend.

Just select the posts that you'd like to change the author for, then click "bulk edit," and you'll see the option (you can also view as many posts as you'd like at the same time; you're not limited to the 25-odd posts you initially see).

No idea how to do it in SQL, but this is how I'd go about it.

Comment: yah. thx but it's a bit more complexed. This is the problem: After updating the database, I made the stupid mistake of removing author rights and allowed the articles submitted by that specific author to default to a different author. Not good. Now, I'm left with a list of IDs from the old database and no clear way to bulk edit using ONLY the post IDs.

Answer (score 0):

// Select the right post_author ID from wp_users table

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_author=1
WHERE ID IN (ID1,ID2,...)
```